# Making a custom form control field required

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, forms, validation

I build a custom form control composed of 3 `mat-select` as shown on the following demo:

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9-material-starter-bejpq7?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

I want to make only month and year field required and make the day field optional in this form control. The examples are generally apply the required to all the components in that user control. But instead of applying to all of 3 select lists, I just want to make required 2 fields of them.

So, how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

If it's possible, you should use angular forms in the DateSelect component as well and pass the value of the form to the onChange function. This way you have control over every input field individually. Mixing angular forms and binding can unnecesarily complicate things.

Comment: You are right, but the reason why I use 3 select list is completely another story. So, I have to use it. Any suggestion under this circumstances?